# Proving $26\mid 5^{12n+3}- 21$

Tags: divisibility

I need to prove that $5^{12n+3} \equiv 21 \pmod{26}.$  I probably need to use Fermat's little theorem but don't know where to start.

Comment: It helps to notice $5^2 = 25 \equiv -1\pmod{26}$

Comment: Fermat’s little theorem is for prime numbers, and $26$ is not prime

Comment: @J.W.Tanner But OP's statement is clear mod 2, so only need mod 13.

Comment: @coffeemath:  I agree.  That’s a start

Comment: Clearly $5^{12n+3} \equiv 21 \pmod{26}\iff 5^{12n+3}-21=26M$ and it is evident that
$5^{12n+3}-21$ is even so divisible by $2$. It follows that it is enough to prove that $5^{12n+3}-21$ is divisible by $13$ or $$5^{12n+3} \equiv 21 \pmod{13}\iff 5^{12n+3} \equiv 8 \pmod{13}\\5^3\cdot5^{12n}\equiv8\pmod{13}$$ Since  $5^{12n}\equiv1\pmod{13}$ (by $FLT$) and $5^3=125\equiv 8\pmod{13}$, we are done.

Comment: $\!\bmod 26\!:\ \color{#c00}{5^2\equiv -1}\Rightarrow a := 5^{3+12n} = 5( \color{#c00}{5^2})^{1+6n}\equiv 5( \color{#c00}{-1})^{1+6n}\equiv -5,\,$ so $\,a-21\equiv -26\equiv 0\,$ by the congruence power & sum rules in the linked dupe. Or, equivalently, use $\,5^{ \color{#0a0}4}\equiv ( \color{#c00}{5^2})^2\equiv (\color{#c00}{-1})^2\equiv 1\,$ so exponents on $5$ can be reduced mod $ \color{#0a0}4$ by **mod order reduction** in the 2nd dupe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fermat's little theorem requires that your modulus is a prime number. Since $26$ is not prime, it won't quite work here (at least, not straight up as is, that is).

Consider, however, that $5^{12n + 3} = 5^{12n} \cdot 5^3$. Taking JMoravitz's hint into consideration that $5^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{26}$, we see that
\begin{align*}
5^{12n + 3} \equiv 5^{12n} \cdot (-5) \equiv 5^{12n} \cdot 21 \pmod{26}.
\end{align*}
If this is, in fact, congruent to $21 \pmod{26}$, then it is necessary to show that $5^{12n} \equiv 1 \pmod{26}$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

By Euler's theorem,  $5^{\varphi (26)}\equiv1 \pmod{26}$.  And $\varphi (26)=12$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).